# Using luxon method fromFormat not working as expected

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

**Update**

Need to use the Full version instead of minified if luxon was unable to parse string to date

https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/install

**TLDR**

I am using ajax and I retrieve the string datetime `2021-04-26 02:41:30 PM` from database. I try to pass this datetime to luxon as follow but it says not parsable:

```
var dt1 = luxon.DateTime.fromFormatExplain("2021-04-26 02:41:30 PM", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
console.log('dt1', dt1);
```

[image]

Isn't this the reason why we use `fromFormat` in order to parse string to date? Thank you

Comment: Try putting the dashes/colons in single-quotes? `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd hh':'mm':'ss a" - But then I also get a valid result with your initial code?

Comment: i tried it's not working. also the regex luxon uses are funny

Comment: It works for me? https://jsfiddle.net/q7cpydje/

Comment: you using luxon@1.3.2? I'm currently on luxon@2.0.1. let me try your version

Comment: good point, I didn't check which version you're using. - It also works with v2.0.1 https://jsfiddle.net/gzcxht8j/

Comment: Hey man thanks for the head up. I was using the minified version but I should've using the Full version.

Comment: that's confusing? the fiddle I shared uses the minified version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235279/discussion-between-4-leave-cover-and-evolutionxbox).

Comment: oh, man. It's 2021 and you said ajax. hehe.

Comment: @ptoinson bro what's other alternative to that?

Comment: Web pages are full on thick networked clients these days. I usually refer to the network layer as I would in any other thick client such as a mobile app, desktop app, etc. It's the 'network layer' that makes udp, tcp, or http request. In a browser it's usually Fetch or Axios and often REST or GraphQL calls that returns JSON. I mean, sure, I guess Ajax is still a thing but I literally have not heard the term used for almost a decade.